# android JSON upload images collection dose not work

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-asynctask

I'm trying to upload some of images after selecting it from my UploadActivity.

```
    public static  int count;
    private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
    ArrayList<String> IPath = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static Uri uri;
    TextView msgLoading;
    //ProgressBar pBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
        msgLoading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgLoading);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Cursor imagecursor = getImageCursor();

                GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
                imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
                imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
                imagecursor.close();
                msgLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        },100);

        final Button uploadBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadDONE);
        uploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
                int cnt = 0;
                String  selectImages = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                        cnt++;
                        selectImages = arrPath[i];
                        IPath.add(selectImages);
                    }
                }

                if (cnt == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please select at least one image",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "You've selected Total " + cnt + " image(s).",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("SelectedImages", String.valueOf(selectImages.toCharArray()));

                    Intent intentMessage = new Intent(UploadActivity.this,
                            ImagesForAds.class);
                    intentMessage.putStringArrayListExtra("IMAGE", IPath);
                    startActivity(intentMessage);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    private Cursor getImageCursor() {
        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        final Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy);
        final int image_column_index = imagecursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
        this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
        this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
        this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
        }
        return imagecursor;
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.checkbox.setId(position);
            holder.imageview.setId(position);
            holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    int id = cb.getId();
                    if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                        cb.setChecked(false);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    } else {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    }
                }
            });

             holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             int id = v.getId();
             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]),
             "image/*");
             startActivity(intent);
             }
             });

            holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
            holder.id = position;
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageview;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        int id;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(UploadActivity.this, ImagesForAds.class);
        UploadActivity.this.finish();
        startActivity(i);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

and it's worked fine, I can back data to my main activity as below :

```
b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null) {
        ImgData = b.getStringArrayList("IMAGE");
        for (int i = 0; i < ImgData.size(); i++) {
            map.add(ImgData.get(i).toString());

        }

    }
```

now it's ok... I need to upload those Images that I selected, here is my asyncTask:

```
public class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String sResponse = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ImagesForAds.this, "Uploading",
                "Please wait...", true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            String url = "myLink";
            int i = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(map.get(i));
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            entity = new MultipartEntity();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

            //entity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody("199"));
            //entity.addPart("club_id", new StringBody("10"));
            entity.addPart("images", new ByteArrayBody(data,
                    "image/jpeg", params[1]));


            Log.i(TAG, "array map: " + map.get(i));


            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                    localContext);
            sResponse = EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(response.getEntity());

            System.out.println("sResponse : " + sResponse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);

        }
        return sResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
        try {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();

            if (sResponse != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        sResponse + " Photo uploaded successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count++;
                if (count < map.size()) {
                    new ImageUploadTask().execute(count + "", "hm" + count
                            + ".jpg");
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }
}
```

and here how I invoke it :

```
int count  = 0;
new ImageUploadTask().execute(count + "", "pk" + count + ".jpg");
```

The issue with `AsyncTask`.. it's upload only 1 image, how I can upload all images I have selected ?

Answer (score 0):

This is your flaw :

```
        if (count < map.size()) {
            new ImageUploadTask().execute(count + "", "hm" + count
                    + ".jpg");
        }
```

not a good idea to create a new ImageUploadTask inside ImageUploadTask.
move your for loop inside doInBackground() and for updating user use publishProgress() and catch that event inside onProgressUpdate.

Read more about AsyncTask : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html